# Rails complex association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feature_products, -> { where("taxonomy_slug = feature_taxonomy_slug") }
  has_many :features, through: :feature_products, class_name: "Feature", source: :feature
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feature_products, -> (object){ where(" feature_taxonomy_slug = ?", object.taxonomy_slug) }, primary_key: :external_id
  has_many :products, through: :feature_products
end

class FeatureProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :feature, primary_key: :external_id
end
```

and the tables are like this:

```
  create_table "feature_products", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.integer "product_id"
     t.integer "feature_id"
     t.string  "feature_taxonomy_slug"
  end

  create_table "features", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.integer "external_id"
     t.string  "name"
     t.string  "taxonomy_slug"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.integer  "company_id"
  end
```

I want to be able to create feature products association like this:

```
feature = Feature.create(external_id: 1234, name: 'WS', taxonomy_slug: 'prop')
Product.create(name: 'XXX', features: [feature])
```

The problem is the table feature_products, it stores the ids but it doesn't store the feature_taxonomy_slug from the feature. Is there any way to store it?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to save the slug in the FeatureProduct model then you are going to have to create one explicitly, i.e.

```
FeatureProduct.create(product: product, feature: feature, feature_taxonomy_slug: feature.taxonomy_slug)
```

I do not understand why you want to save the slug in the FeatureProduct model.
Is there a reason why you do not want to access it through the product.features association?

Comment: Because external_id is not unique ,features can have repeated external_id, but they are unique with the slug